# Filter DataTable with any match of a string

Tags: c#, sql, regex, linq, datatable

I was wondering if it would be possible to apply a Filter or Select on a .NET **DataTable** that would match **any row** that contains **at least one word or letter** of the search term, eg:

> **Search Term**: "San South Francisco"
>
> **Would Match**: "North **San Francisco**", 
>   "**San Francisco**", "**South** Los Angeles", "Peak **North**"
>
> ****: Because they contain either "San" or "Francisco" or "South".

I know it sounds crazy but any advise it much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DataTable.Select supports like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var str = "South San Francisco";
var filteredRows = dt.Select("Column LIKE '%" + str + "%'");
```

for more complex filters, use Linq to DataSets

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Where(dr => 
                        {
                            var wordsSplited = dr.Field<string>("Column").Split(' ');
                            var words = new HashSet<string>(wordsSplited);

                            var inputSplitted = str.Split(' ');
                            return words.Intersect(inputSplitted).Any();
                        });
```

Comment: Thanks, my sample wasn't very clear, I need to match any word even if in between it there isn't a match, eg: "San South Francisco".

Comment: You can use linq to dataset, something like dt.AsEnumerable().Where(dr => dr.Field<string>("Column").Split(' ') contains words from input

Comment: see edited answer for more details... I assume that word orders are not important in input and column... but you can do any variations there cause you have text and column... hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this if I understand clearly;

```
var south = "South";
var san =  "San";
var fran = "Francisco";
var filteredRows = dt.Select("Column LIKE '%" + south + "%' OR Column LIKE '%" + san + "%' OR Column LIKE '%" + fran + "%'");
```

Comment: I changed it to `AND` in stead of `OR` because I only want rows that have all the words. I keep forgetting that you can use SQL syntax in the datatable select method, it's actually so simple